# why does this function change list twice?

Tags: python

```
def foo(var=[]):
    var.append(1)
    return var

print(foo())
print(foo())
```

This produces:

```
[1]
[1,1]
```

but it should be just

```
[1]
[1]
```

lists are mutable, but we call function foo with no args  in it. So it should always start with the default empty list var. 
Why does it 'recognize' there is var list and it's changed?

Comment: Defaults are only evaluated once when the definition is evaluated. Every call shares the same default objects. Also this is a duplicate.

Comment: @DanD. Great comment! Put it into an answer with some detail. This deserves to be an answer for this question.

Comment: @DanD. , yes, if you answer - i will upvote & accept!

Comment: @EvgeniiKlepilin thx u Evgeni